# How to read a textarea field using C# and SOQL in Salesforce?

Tags: c#, .net, salesforce

How can I read a textarea field using C# and SOQL in Salesforce. I am using Salesforce partner WSDL. Currently I am using getFieldValue() to get String values from the SOQL result set but the same is not working for textarea. I think I am missing something here.

Thanks for looking into it.

Code for getting field value

```
 private string getFieldValue(string fieldName, System.Xml.XmlElement[] fields)
        {
            string returnValue = "";
            if (fields != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (fields[i].LocalName.ToLower().Equals(fieldName.ToLower()))
                    {
                        returnValue = fields[i].InnerText;
                    }
                }
            }
            return returnValue;
        }


 private System.Xml.XmlElement GetNewXmlElement(string Name, string nodeValue)
        {
            System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            System.Xml.XmlElement xmlel = doc.CreateElement(Name);
            xmlel.InnerText = nodeValue;
            return xmlel;
        }
```

Now getFieldValue works in almost all scenarios apart from textarea.

Comment: perhaps a code sample of what you currently have would suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the record using the debugger can you see a value in the field? This could boil down to many things, some intricacy of the C# library, or, for instance, if your salesforce user doesn't have access to that particular field (due to field level security) then the value would not be returned to you even if you've queried that field.

My suggestions:

1. Ensure your user does have access to that field, using SOQL explorer or similar to verify this, or just check the configuration in Salesforce.
2. Check the documentation for any special consideration in relation to text areas, these can't be checked in a WHERE clause for instance.
3. See if you can see a value in the field using the debugger.
4. Post a code sample :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is no security issue. Debugger does not show any data in it. I have added the code sample anyway. Hope it helps

Comment: So the value isn't in visible in the entry in `fields` corresponding to the text area. Did you check using SOQL explorer or similar?

Comment: Got it. SOQL was somehow passing on the blank value. I had to regenerate the WSDL classes to fix the issue. Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, must have been that the field was added after the WSDL was initially generated. Glad you got it sorted!